# Created my first webcrawler, how do I get a "URL stack-trace"/history of URL's for each endpoint?

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, python-requests, scrapy

I created a web crawler that, given a base_url, will spider out and find all possible endpoints. While I am able to get all the endpoints, I need a way to figure out how I got there in the first place -- a 'url stack-trace' persay or breadcrumbs of url's leading to each endpoint.

I first start by finding all url's given a base url. Since the sublinks I'm looking for are within a json, I thought the best way to do this would be using a variation of a recurisve dictionary example I found here: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/some-more-python-recursion-examples/:

```
import requests
import pytest
import time

BASE_URL = "https://www.my-website.com/"

def get_leaf_nodes_list(base_url):
    """
    :base_url: The starting point to crawl
    :return: List of all possible endpoints
    """

    class Namespace(object):
        # A wrapper function is used to create a Namespace instance to hold the ns.results variable
        pass
    ns = Namespace()
    ns.results = []

    r = requests.get(BASE_URL)
    time.sleep(0.5)  # so we don't cause a DDOS?
    data = r.json()

    def dict_crawler(data):
        # Retrieve all nodes from nested dict
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for item in data.values():
                dict_crawler(item)
        elif isinstance(data, list) or isinstance(data, tuple):
            for item in data:
                dict_crawler(item)
        else:
            if type(data) is unicode:
                if "http" in data:  # If http in value, keep going
                    # If data is not already in ns.results, don't append it
                    if str(data) not in ns.results:  
                        ns.results.append(data)
                        sub_r = requests.get(data)
                        time.sleep(0.5)  # so we don't cause a DDOS?
                        sub_r_data = sub_r.json()
                        dict_crawler(sub_r_data)

    dict_crawler(data)
    return ns.results
```

To reiterate, the get_leaf_nodes_list does a get request and looks for any values within the json for a url (if 'http' string is in the value for each key) to recursively do more get requests until there's no url's left.

So to reiterate here are the questions I have:

- How do I get a linear history of all the url's I hit to get to each endpoint?
- Corollary to that, how would I store this history? As the leaf nodes list grows, my process gets expontentially slower and I am wondering if there's a better data type out there to store this information or a more efficient process to the code above.

Comment: You could also look at loading the json using the json module `import json`  https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: More easy and efficient would be to use beautifulsoup. There are methods to parse html file and get the links. it will make your code more clear and with less loops.

Comment: @david-zemens : sorry, I'm not understanding how would that help in getting a linear history of the url endpoints (ie. how I got to the endpoint given the base url.)

Comment: @b10n1k thanks, I'll definitely check that out